# how to get certain words from user input

Tags: python, user-input

Hello i am trying to make my program check for certain words in the user input. For example: The user types "add the numbers 6+6" what the programs does is it has a dictionary and checks the words in the dictionary and compares them to the words in the user input this example is "add". If the word add is in the user input then it checks for numbers and also math symbols this example is "6+6" then it outputs the answer?

I have tried:

```
if test == "add":
         do something
```

but this will not work unless the word "add" is all by itself. any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Well unless you do some tough machine learning to recognize the sentence's structure, your results are going to be really shaky. Ofc you can look for `if "add" in input` then use regex to parse a "somewhat" mathematical expression, but that's no good I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work only in the cases like `add 6+6` or `6+6 add` or `add <some_text> 6+6` etc.

```
   string = input()
    if 'add' in string:
        string = string.split('+')
        no1 = int(string[0].split()[-1])
        no2 = int(string[1].split()[0])
        print(no1 + no2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the input words and check them in your dictionary like

```
for word in input:
    if word in dic:
       pass

    fail
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string.split() to split up the text into each word.

Then you can test each word individually for key words.

Details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Look up the split method.

I'm pretty sure the split method by default returns a list of words split up by white space characters. So for example:

test_list = input.split()

test_list[1] should be 'add'

Best way to find out is to test it yourself, but I think it is something along those lines.

Cheers